# Angular - Bootstrap: Page navigation (Next and back button) using Angular UI-route not working when changing the state from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to achieve page navigation (Next and back button) using Angular UI-route. I am changing the state from controller and it is getting changed on view as well but is not redirecting me to that page.
I have achieved it using button click using $state.go('stateName') but I want use Bootstrap page for this .

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KV9LEC?p=preview)

here is my code

```js
$stateProvider
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html'
    })
    .state('settings.profile', {
      url: '/profile',
      templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileController'
    })
    .state('settings.account', {
      url: '/account',
      templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountController'
    })
    .state('settings.profile1', {
      url: '/profile1',
      template: 'settings.profile1'

    })
    .state('settings.account1', {
      url: '/account1',
      template: 'settings.account1'

    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings/profile');


// controlller  
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   
    $scope.nextState = 'settings.account';
    $scope.previousState = $state.current;
    //alert('$stateChangeStart')
  });
```

```html
 <ul class="pager">
    {{nextState}}
  <li><a  ui-sref=".{{previousState}}">Previous</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click=".{{nextState}}">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I observed, if you use ui-sref with some scope variable, first time it works properly and generate href related to state. But when scope variable changes href is not changed, may be a issue.

Not sure why **$stateChangeSuccess** is not working properly. I am handling states from rootScope, but you can move this code SettingsController.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tAAtWK?p=preview)

```
example.run(function($rootScope, $state){
  var arrState = [];
  var states = $state.stateRegistry.states;

  angular.forEach(states, function(key, value) {
    if (value !== "") {
      arrState.push(value)
    }
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
    var n = !$state.current.name ? 1 : arrState.indexOf($state.current.name) + 1;
    $rootScope.next = arrState[n];  
    var p = !$state.current.name ? 0 : arrState.indexOf($state.current.name) - 1;
    if (p <0 ) p = 0;
    $rootScope.previous = arrState[p];  
  });
  $rootScope.goNext = function () {
    $state.go($rootScope.next);
  }

  $rootScope.goPrevious = function () {
    $state.go($rootScope.previous);
  };
});
```

Used goNext & goPrevious with ng-click.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil I was looking for similar kinda solution.